# Reference from Shankaracharya's Prasnatraya for Panchayatna Puja?

Tags: vedanta, adi-shankaracharya

Can anyone quote Shankaracharya's Bhasya in Prasnatraya to prove Non Duality between 5 Devas(Vishnu Shiva Devi Ganesha Surya) or Panchayatna Puja?
Note : I am aware of quote in Mahabharata but I want from SHankaracharya Bhasya

Comment: I don't think you will find a direct reference to the panchayatna or shanmatha pooja in the bhashyas of Adi Shankara.

Comment: Sir is it possible to find non duality of 5 Devatas in his Prasnatraya Bhasya @GIRIBLR

Comment: I don't think so.

Comment: Sir any other mention in his works about Non duality of 5 Devas? @GIRIBLR

Comment: I know they aren't different and he composed stotras on all but I wanted some kind of proof from his works sir @GIRIBLR Btw what he composed on Lord Surya sir

Comment: There is something called aruna panchakam written by him but unfortunately not available now.

Comment: Ok sir no problem @GIRIBLR

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"any other mention in his works about Non duality of 5 Devas?"

In [jivanmuktananda lahiri](https://kamakoti.org/shlokas/kshlok23.htm), verse 14, he talks about the equality of these Gods.

> क्वचिच्छैवैः सार्थं क्वचिदपि च शाक्तैः सह वसन् कदा विष्णोर्भक्तैः
> क्वचिदपि च सौरैः सह वसन् । कदा गाणापत्यैर्गतसकलभेदोऽद्वयतया मुनिर्न
> व्यामोहं भजति गुरुदीक्षाक्षततमाः ॥ १४॥
>
> Kvacicchaivaih sárdham kvacidapi ca shálaih saha raman Kadá
> vishnorbhaktaih kvacidapi ca sauraih saha vasan Kadá
> gánápatyairgatasakala bhedo'dvayatayá munir ca vyámoham bhajati
> gurudèkshá kshata tamáh (14)
>
> Living at ease somewhere in the company of shaivas and elsewhere with
> sháktas, And still in another place with the devotees of Vishnu or the
> Sun, Sometimes with Ganapati's worshippers and thus with all
> difference gone with the feeling of one-ness; The sage, with ignorance
> dispelled by Guru's grace (dèkshá), is not at all deluded.

Comment: Thanks a lot sir